# Show only every 2nd row after running a WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to show only every 2nd row after selecting something from my DB.

My select looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table where partnerID = '1'
```

Now from the results of that select query I want to get only every 2nd row.

Is that possible ?

Comment: Is there a numbered row field, or do you want every other result of the query?

Comment: I want every other row just from that specific query, there is a numbered row field, but the content could be of another partner.

Comment: *"every 2nd row"*. Ordered by what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$count = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    $count++;
    if($count % 2 == 1) continue;

    // What you want to do with the rows you don't want to skip here...
}
```

On a side note, you can use this same strategy to only show every 3rd row, or every 4th row, simply by changing what number you put next to the modulus operator

```
if($count % 3 != 0) continue; // Show only every third row
if($count % 4 != 0) continue; // Show only every fourth row
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  @n := @n + 1 AS position,
            t.*
    FROM (SELECT @n:=0) counter,
         table t
    WHERE partnerID = 1)
AS query
WHERE MOD(position,2) = 0
```

Comment: @PaulBellora I have edited the answer - it seems to work now.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in the following way:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
      @I := @I + 1 AS rowNumber,
      tablename.*

    FROM
      tablename,
      (SELECT @I := 0) VT1

    WHERE partnerID = 2

    ORDER BY ID
) NumberedRows
WHERE MOD(rowNumber, 2)=0
;
```

Comment: @ypercube: Right. That's what I meant (in the database)

Comment: @Cylindric: you have missed the `where partnerID = '1'` part.

Comment: @ypercube: If OP can't add that in himself, he should slowly back away from his computer now ;)

Comment: I'm assuming `table` isn't the real name of the table either, so there seemed little point making it match a hypothetical example exactly.

Comment: @Cylindric: Future readers may be wondering why you removed that part while you added `ORDER BY ID`. (Is that better practice? Was it needed? Is it optional?, etc...)

Comment: @ypercube good point, I added a WHERE to match the ORDER for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right answer, but it looks like you would need to use something like MOD function (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod)

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id & 1;
```

Would return odd rows

Comment: Your SQL makes a huge assumption about id's consecutiveness so it is ill-advised.

Comment: It makes assumptions about the IDs' consecutiveness and also about the consecutiveness of the IDs that meet the partnerID=1 criterion. The OP wants to take every second row from among the rows returned by an arbitrary select statement, not just every second row from the table.

Comment: Thanks guys for the info, wasn't 100% sure as I stated in my answer. Just trying to help.